# Random "S" appearing when not in HTML code

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

This is the most bizarre problem I've ever SO-ed, but there is a random "s" appearing on my code.  This is on Rails 7, but I'm honestly not thinking it's a Rails/ERB issue.

Here is the "s" in question:
[image: Random S]

Here is the code the way it's rendered (through inspect source code), in which **NO S APPEARS**:

```
<div class="search mt-3 mb-4">
    <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Filter products list...">
  </div>

  <div id="searchable-products-list">
    <div id="products">
      <table class="table small">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Brand</th>
            <th scope="col">Product</th>
            <th scope="col">LGW SKU</th>
            <th scope="col">Model</th>
            <th scope="col">Color</th>
            <th scope="col">Voltage</th>
            <th scope="col">MSRP</th>
            <th scope="col">MAP</th>
            <th scope="col">Images</th>            
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
```

Yet here's a screenshot of the code where the " s " is clearly visible:

[image: Screenshot of S existing in the code]

I have done a `command + f` in my CSS/SCSS and there are no `before` or `after` statements in the entire thing.

Can anyone help me figure out where this thing is coming from?

Comment: add the code for the whole products div to your question

Comment: also check your css for anything with `content:`

Comment: The code (3rd picture) is not the actual HTML code but the HTML structure, right? Perhaps you want to inspect your real HTML code. I once run into a similar issue where I had a div-tag around the tr-tag. This was sorted outside the table. So there might be an "s" outside of a tr/td-tag

Comment: do you have javascript demons wreaking havoc on your page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have inadvertently included something like this in your page:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>s
  </tr>
</table>
```

The html parser in the browser doesn't know what to do with the spurious 's' so it puts it before the table. Look carefully at the html you are generating, the spurious letter might not be in the place that the browser is telling you after it parses your markup.

Comment: Yup, the dom as interpreted by your browser and shown in the inspector tools doesn't always match the markup. There's an `s` somewhere in the table, but not inside of a cell, as is semantically required in a table.

Comment: it can be useful to have a look at the raw response from the network tab to track down that rouge "s".